# Finding the length of $HD$ in a cyclic right angled $\triangle BCD$ where $CF = 5$ and $FH = 3$ and $FG \perp BD$.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Source:** *Regional Math Olympiad of BD*

> Let $\triangle BCD$ be a right angled triangle where $\angle BCD$ = 90$^\circ$. $FG$ is perpendicular to $BD$ from any point $F$ on $CD$. Line $BF$ intersects the circumcircle of $BCD$ at $E$. $EG$ and $CD$ intersects at $H$. $CF = 5$, $FH = 3$ then what is value of $HD$?

**Here is a liklier figure of the contextual problem:**

[image]

Here I noticed that the length of $FH$ is dependant on the length of $BC$. But I couldn't relate the $FH$ with $BC$ by any equation I have tried with. It was too hard for me to solve. So, which method should I use or in which way should I proceed?

*I'll be highly gladful if it is slightly edited for better understanding.*

Comment: As you've drawn the figure, $E$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $D$ to the hypotenuse, and $HE$ is not perpendicular to $BC$. That's not what the text says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x= HD$. Since $$\angle FED = \angle FGD = 90^{\circ}$$ the quadrilateral $DEFG$ is cyclic. So $$\angle FGE = \angle FDE = \angle CDE = \angle CBE = \angle CGF$$

and thus $FG$ is (inner) angle bisector for $\angle CGH$ and since $BD\bot FG$ the $BD$ is (outer) angle bisector for $\angle CGH$. By the angle bisector theorem we have:

$$ {CF\over FH} = {CD\over DH} \implies {5\over 3} = {8+x\over x}$$

So $x= 12$.

Comment: This was fast. Have you even read my solution?

Comment: Nope. But I was so much delighted after getting that solution. I think, in order to prove the $DEFG$ as cyclic, we need to show $\angle FGD$ = 90$^\circ$.